# Executing a script using ISQL

Tags: firebird, interbase, isql

I'm creating a simple isql script but it's not working and I need some help to find out whats wrong with it.
I need to connect to a database and execute a SQL file. This is my script called script.sql:

```
CONNECT 'localhost:C:\Monde\Servidor\db\monde.fdb' USER 'SYSDBA' PASSWORD 'masterkey';    
update usuario  
set senha = 'MYkWEn0kHLHHdm'  
where login = 'rose'
```

When I try to connect to my database using.:

```
isql.exe -i script.sql
```

I get this follow message.:

```
Use CONNECT or CREATE DATABASE to specify a database
Expected end of statement, encountered EOF
```

Answer (score 9):

Ok although it's an old question I found out how to do it, you just need to append de -q parameter, like this:

```
isql.exe -q -i script.sql
```

Source:

[iSQL Reference form Destructor.de](http://www.destructor.de/firebird/isql.htm)

Answer (score 5):

Append a semicolon to the end of the `UPDATE` statement:

```
CONNECT 'localhost:C:\Monde\Servidor\db\monde.fdb' USER 'SYSDBA' PASSWORD 'masterkey';
update usuario
set senha = 'MYkWEn0kHLHHdm'
where login = 'rose';
```

Comment: Use CONNECT or CREATE DATABASE to specify a database  
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 42000  
Dynamic SQL Error  
-SQL error code = -104  
-Unexpected end of command - line 1, column 8  
After line 1 in file usuario.sql  
Command error: set senha = 'MYkWEn0kHLHHdm'  
where login = 'rose'

Comment: @user: put a newline after the last line.

Comment: @user: put the cursor to the end of file, after the final semicolon, and press `Enter`.

Comment: @user: can't help you then. I just reproduced this on my `Firebird 1.5`, it works. Please copy and paste the commands from my answer.

Comment: Well, it worked. I forgot to add a comma after "update usuario". Thank you so much for your help.