# Run multiple insert queries against firebird database using isql

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5, isql

I have requirement of `inserting enormous data in table of firebird database around 40K entries`. I got my scripts ready but while executing it using flameRobin, the UI just got hang forever while inserting such enormous data in one go.

I know it would be fine if i execute my insert queries in blocks of 255 queries but i want to know if there is any `bulk insert tool available for Firebird` to do such entries while reading from my scripts.sql file.

After some googling, I came across `isql` tool but not able to execute the scripts against it. Can someone guide me to any other tool or the proper documentation to enter such enormous data in one go?

I have `firebird version 2.5` installed on my system.

Comment: About using `isql` - why are you "not able to execute the scripts against it"? Dou you get an error? If so then what is the error message? `isql` which comes with FB is the official "command line interface" to FB and in general it works fine. BTW add `COMMIT WORK;` statement into your script after, say, each 1000 statements, to see does it make difference.

Comment: I just tested with 3-4 `insert` queries, it works fine. But with `40K` insert queries it seems to get hang. I followed the approach as per this question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821562/executing-a-script-using-isql. Works good for 2-3 queries but not with such enormous data. :(

Comment: Add the `COMMIT WORK;` statement after every 1000 `insert` statements or so to see does it make difference.

Comment: Command Prompt was in `hang` state for almost 10-12 mins but data was successfully inserted when i checked the database once prompt becomes active. Thanks..!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

40K doesn't seem a big number for me. In our cases we work with millions of records without significant problems. I think the reason of hunging is Flamerobin trying to parse whole script or something like this. Use [isql](http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/isql.html) utility instead. First, prepare a text file with commands:

```
CONNECT "your_server:your_database_name" USER "sysdba" PASSWORD "masterkey";
INSERT ... ;
INSERT ... ;
....
INSERT ... ;
EXIT;
```

Then run an utility from a dos prompt:

```
isql < your_script.sql
```

Also consider to deactivate indices and drop foreign keys for the table for a bulk insert operation and restore them afterwards.

Comment: I tried this with small data but everytime i run this in prompt i got this message- `Use CONNECT or CREATE DATABASE to specify a database`. But when i checked my database, entry was there in table. Did you too get this message?

Comment: No. It works fine for me. I can send you a small database and a script.

Comment: I just tested with my scripts too. After 10-12 mins, message did appear but when i check the database, entries where there. So, message don't matter as long as i am getting the ouput. Thanks a lot.!!

Answer (score 8):

You can use EXECUTE BLOCK to stuff more inserts into a single statement. Something like this:

```
set term !! ;
EXECUTE BLOCK AS BEGIN
  insert into ... values ...;
  insert into ... values ...;
  insert into ... values ...;
  insert into ... values ...;
  ....etc.
  insert into ... values ...;
END!!
```

You can group them in 100 at a time or similar. This should make things go much faster and also improve FlameRobin's parsing.

isql is still faster, but this gives you better error control. It's really hard to debug stuff if some inserts in the middle fail with isql.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `EXTERNAL`.

```
command.CommandText = @"CREATE TABLE TEMP1 EXTERNAL FILE 'c:\ExternalTables\Ext.ext'(ID INTEGER,CRLF CHAR(2));";
int j=command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```