# firebird embedded multiple inserts using .net provider

Tags: c#, .net, firebird, firebird-embedded

I am developing an application that will use firebird embedded and/or postgres depending on user sophistication.  The argument for firebird embedded is that there should be less installation, firewall, UAC, etc issues.  So far postgres is like walking on clouds but I have hit a roadblock with firebird.  The app is .net and I am using this provider http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-provider/ version 3.0.2

Everything technically works but with firebird embedded I am inserting only around 100 records per second whereas with postgres it's over 3000 per second!  With postgres I launch a large amount of INSERT INTO... statements as one command and it's fine.  For firebird it's not going well.  Here is what does work (slowly)

```
String query = @"INSERT INTO Customers(ID, Name, SiteID) VALUES(1,'delta',2);
INSERT INTO Customers(ID, Name, SiteID) VALUES(2,'phoenix',2);
";
FbScript fbs = new FbScript(query);
fbs.Parse();
FbConnection fbc = new FbConnection(ConnectionString);

FbBatchExecution fbe = new FbBatchExecution(fbc, fbs);
fbe.Execute(true);
```

However, I am trying to do without the parse.  Something similar to the second answer here [Run multiple insert queries against firebird database using isql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986774/run-multiple-insert-queries-against-firebird-database-using-isql) or here http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq336/

```
String sql = @"set term ^ ;
EXECUTE BLOCK AS BEGIN
INSERT INTO Customers(ID, Name, SiteID) VALUES(1,'delta',2);
INSERT INTO Customers(ID, Name, SiteID) VALUES(2,'phoenix',2);
end^";

FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand();            
PrepareCommand(cmd, connection, (FbTransaction)null, CommandType.Text, sql, commandParameters, out mustCloseConnection);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

With this I get the exception

```
Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 1, column 5
term
```

Is the first way the only way?  It's so slow :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the `set term` statements, these are `isql` [specific thing](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/user_manuals/html/isql-set.html#isql-set-term). So try

```
String sql = @"EXECUTE BLOCK AS BEGIN
INSERT INTO Customers(ID, Name, SiteID) VALUES(1,'delta',2);
INSERT INTO Customers(ID, Name, SiteID) VALUES(2,'phoenix',2);
END";
```

Answer (score 1):

Ain already gave an answer on how to fix this, but as an explanation: commandline tools like isql need to know when a statement is complete and can be executed. They use `;` as the terminator. However inside PSQL blocks (stored procedures and `EXECUTE BLOCK`, the `;` is also a statement terminator.

To keep the isql tool from sending an incomplete statement to the server (thus causing a parser error), the command `SET TERM` exists to switch the statement terminator of the command line (isql). Now isql isn't the only one that uses `SET TERM`, for example flamerobin supports it as well.

With drivers like the Firebird .NET provider and its `FbCommand`object, you are executing a single statement so there is no need for statement terminators (nor are they supported by Firebird server), therefor `SET TERM` is not necessary nor supported.