# How to convert parameters substring to the column type in C#?

Tags: c#, casting, substring, firebird, firebird2.5

I have an `INSERT` with one `VARCHAR` parameter.
SQL looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO FLAGS (TIME_STAMP, FLAG) 
SELECT SUBSTRING(@s1 FROM 1 FOR 23), SUBSTRING(@s1 FROM 24 FOR 2) 
FROM RDB$DATABASE;
```

And sending method like this:

```
using (FbConnection connection = new FbConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
        var command = new FbCommand(sqlCommand, connection, transaction);
        command.Parameters.Add("@s1", "2018-09-12 08:37:51.00083");
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Column `TIME_STAMP` is `TIMESTAMP` and column `FLAG` is `INTEGER`. In the real application there will be several rows in the INSERT, not just one. There will be also more columns so I would like to keep number of parameters for one row as low as possible.
If I run this code, it gives me:
`Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll`

If I change the command like this:

```
INSERT INTO FLAGS (TIME_STAMP, FLAG) 
SELECT SUBSTRING(@s1 FROM 1 FOR 23), CAST(SUBSTRING(@s1 FROM 24 FOR 2) AS INTEGER) 
FROM RDB$DATABASE;
```

It gives me this error:

```
Exception thrown: 'FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbException' in 
FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll
Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -804
Data type unknown
```

FWIR this should be possible. At least this works in FlameRobin (version with `CAST` also works):

```
SET TERM ^ ; 
EXECUTE BLOCK AS 
DECLARE s1 VARCHAR(25) = '2018-09-12 08:37:51.00083'; 
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO FLAGS (TIME_STAMP, FLAG) 
SELECT SUBSTRING(:s1 FROM 1 FOR 23), SUBSTRING(:s1 FROM 24 FOR 2) 
FROM RDB$DATABASE;
END^ 
SET TERM ; ^
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

**EDIT**
Result should be:

```
TIME_STAMP              | FLAG
------------------------+-----
2018-09-12 08:37:51.000 | 83
```

Comment: I would suggest considering something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17882366/firebird-embedded-multiple-inserts-using-net-provider and specifying each parameter independently.

Comment: Actually I had multiple inserts in `EXECUTE BLOCK` but have problems with speed and memory consumption, so I am looking for some other solutions that could be more efficient.

Comment: Try specify the data type when adding the parameter.

Comment: @CaiqueCPereira The problem is that there could be more data types in one parameter and it looks like I need to specify the correct data type after substring and I am not able to do that.

Comment: "There will be also more columns so I would like to keep number of parameters for one row as low as possible" - a very weird idea. You want to remove type safety and deterministic behavior for the sake of fuzzy heuristics and no warrants. For obscure reason you want to shoot yourself into the foot. Well, you just did.

Comment: Get rid from `SELECT` - it does not belong there. `INSERT INTO FLAGS (TIME_STAMP, FLAG) VALUES (@S1, @S2)`. Also it seems you should not add "@" to the parameter names - see http://bobby-tables.com/adodotnet and also see https://www.ibprovider.com/eng/examples/lcpi_oledb_net__c001__example_0005.html

Comment: @Arioch'The Linking to IBProvider documentation is not right when the OP is using FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient, and that driver definitely does support using `@` in parameter names (as does System.Data.SqlClient for SQL Server)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel that documentation also uses Ado.Net framework in C#, so while it may not be applied verbatim - it demonstrates the relevant concepts and one example of their implementation. Is there equally extensive set of examples published on FirebirdClient site ?

Comment: @Arioch'The That is not my point. You are making claims that are not correct based on documentation of a different driver.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I base them upon many examples I have seen around net and upon BT site first and IP site only second. Frankly, if there would had been INSERT/VALUES example on BT I would not even look into IP site here. And there was a reason I made it only comment not answer and even after that I wrote >>Also(1) it seems(2) you should not add "@"....."<<

Comment: @Arioch'The Both standard ADO.net documentation and the [examples on the Firebird site](https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-examples-of-use/) suggest it is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebird cannot infer the datatype of a parameter in the select list in most situations (there are exceptions, but this is not one of them). You will need to explicitly cast it to define the data type and length. Note that this only works with Firebird 2.5 or higher.

You'll need to use:

```
INSERT INTO FLAGS (TIME_STAMP, FLAG) 
SELECT SUBSTRING(cast(@s1 as varchar(25)) FROM 1 FOR 23), CAST(SUBSTRING(cast(@s1 as varchar(25)) FROM 24 FOR 2) AS INTEGER) 
FROM RDB$DATABASE
```

It would however be far better to do this client side and just use a normal `insert into .. values (..,..)` using appropriate types than using stringly typed things.

The reason it works in the `execute block`, is because there you have already defined `s1` to be a `varchar(25)`

Comment: It works, thank you. I would like to try this approach, because I am trying to reduce memory consumption (and increase speed) for periodically inserting many rows (around 400k every time) and according to [this article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/comparing-multiple-rows-insert-vs-single-row-insert-with-three-data-load-methods/) this solution could help me with that.

Comment: I also tried the recommended way (set of `INSERT INTO` in `EXECUTE BLOCK` with parameters), but it gives me -901 undefined message number - even with just one row which works well if I remove `EXECUTE BLOCK AS BEGIN` from the beginning and `END` from an end.

Comment: @Artholl That depends exactly on how you used the execute block; parameters need to be passed to the execute block correctly. And really, don't rely on articles written for different database systems and assume it will translate directly to another database system.

Comment: I just wanted to test if that solution gives me some improvement also in Firebird, I definitely don't rely on that. So far it looks like I will not use it. But thanks to you I learned something about Firebird which could help me somehow in the future, so it was not complete waste of time :-)