# query database and export via txt file

Tags: firebird

I need to make a select query in a firebird database and export the result in a .txt file.

Is there a way to make this via sql ? Or command line ?

Appreciate any help

Comment: there is fbexport utility on SourceForge

Comment: you can also use isql running from script https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821562 fused with mundane command line output redirect

Comment: Most query tools provide support for this. There is nothing built-in in Firebird itself for this.

Comment: Hello Mark, thank you. I will look for it.